# Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service"

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, mysql-connector

I have some problems with starting mysql

```
    sudo systemctl status mysql
     ● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset>
     Active: activating (start) since Mon 2022-08-08 13:12:18 +06; 22s ago
     Process: 37609 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code>
     Main PID: 37617 (mysqld)
      Status: "Server startup in progress"
       Tasks: 13 (limit: 2388)
     Memory: 259.8M
        CPU: 503ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
             └─37617 /usr/sbin/mysqld

Там 08 13:12:18 belyash-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Там 08 13:12:18 belyash-VirtualBox systemd[1]: mysql.service: Consumed 9.470s >
Там 08 13:12:18 belyash-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server>
lines 1-15/15 (END)
```

Also this

```
root@belyash-VirtualBox:/home/belyash# sudo systemctl start mysql
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xeu mysql.service" for details.
```

I just stop the work of mysql and when i want to start it again it gives me this errors